# PDEs and algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

Let $P$ be an order $d$ differential operator with constant coefficients and consider a PDE of the form $Pf = \delta$. Taking the Fourier transform of $P$ we get a degree $d$ polynomial whose zero locus is an affine hypersurface $X_P\subset\mathbb{A}^n$.

Does there exist any result relating algebraic geometric properties of $X_P$ and analytic properties of the fundamental solution of $Pf = \delta$? For instance if we know that $X_P$ has no real point can we say something about the fundamental solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What has been studied more extensively is the top order term, which is known as the principal symbol. Since it is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, it defines a real projective algebraic variety, known as  the characteristic variety.

The relationship between properties of the characteristic variety and and those of the PDE has been studied extensively. For example, if there are no real points, then $P$ is called elliptic. Such differential operators behave particularly nicely. Beyond that the principal symbol can be used to identify hyperbolic differential operators, differential operators of real principal type, etc.  A large part of a subject called microlocal analysis is devoted to studying all of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you recommend some references where I could study these things?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know only relatively old references. There might be more recent surveys and books. Michael Taylor has written some books about pseudodifferential operators, which explain a lot of this. You can find them listed on his homepage. Lars Hörmander wrote a 4 volume series titled The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators. François Treves has a recent book titled Analytic Partial Differential Equations that looks quite nice.

Answer (score 10):

This obvious connection between constant coefficient PDEs and algebraic varieties has not escaped the notice of eminent mathematicians. Not being an expert, I can't really say how active the study of this and related topics is now. But here are some older references whose citation trees might lead one closer to the state of the art.

These papers deal with relating directions (cones) in which fundamental solutions don't propagate with the algebraic properties of the symbol of the PDE:

> *Atiyah, Michael F.; Bott, Raoul; Gårding, Lars*, [**Lacunas for hyperbolic differential operators with constant coefficients.I**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02394570), Acta Math. 124, 109-189 (1970). [ZBL0191.11203](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.11203).
>
> *Atiyah, Michael F.; Bott, Raoul; Gårding, Lars*, [**Lacunas for hyperbolic differential operators with constant coefficients. II**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392039), Acta Math. 131, 145-206 (1973). [ZBL0266.35045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0266.35045).

I believe that Malgrange is credited with putting on its final footing the theory of the existence of fundamental solutions for arbitrary constant coefficient PDEs, with parallel and later developments credited to Palamodov (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/186874) for where to find more detailed references):

> *Malgrange, Bernard*, Sur les systèmes différentiels à coefficients constants. (On differential systems with constant coefficients), Equ. Derivees partielles, Paris 1962, Colloques internat. Centre nat. Rech. sci. 117, 113-122 (1963). [ZBL0231.46073](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0231.46073).
>
> *Palamodov, V. P.*, Linear differential operators with constant coefficients, Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 168. Springer-Verlag. VIII, 443 p. (1970). [ZBL0191.43401](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.43401).

Comment: Leon Ehrenpreis also played a central role in the theory of PDEs with constant coefficients.

Comment: The papers of Atiyah, Bott, Gårding study the singular set of a distribution solution to a constant coefficient hyperbolic. This was also studied by Lax and probably others. A hyperbolic PDE is a generalization of the wave equation in physics. Physicists knew that the propgation of a singularity in a solution would propagate through a medium along curves that depended on properties of the medium. All of this was made rigorous and extended to hyperbolic PDEs. Hörmander extended it beyond that, and his answer is quite beautiful.

Comment: @DeaneYang About Ehrenpreis, yes you are right. From what I gather, his contributions came about a decade earlier than those of Malgrange and Palamodov, so references to him should already be in their bibliographies.

Comment: There is an interesting connection between lacunas of hyperbolic operators, and a quantitative version of the Toeplitz-Hausdorff's Theorem. See Th. Gallay & D. S. The numerical measure of a complex matrix. Comm. Pure Appl. Math. (2011)  https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.20374

Answer (score 7):

A most important result is missing in the previous answers, namely the characterization by Lars Hörmander of hypoellipticity in his seminal paper,
*On the theory of general partial differential operators*, Acta Math. 94 (1955), 161–248 [MR 0076151].

Let $P$ be a polynomial on $\mathbb C^n$ and let us define the characteristic set of $P$ by
$$
\text{char} P=\{\zeta \in \mathbb C^n, P(\zeta)=0\}.
\tag{$\sharp$}
$$
The operator $P(D)$ is said to be hypoelliptic whenever for all distributions $u\in \mathscr D'(\mathbb R^n)$,
$$
\text{SingSupport }[u]=\text{SingSupport } [P(D)u],
\tag{$\flat$}$$
where the singular support of $v$ is defined as the complement of the largest open subset where $v$ is $C^\infty$.
In the aforementioned article, L. Hörmander proved that $P(D)$ is hypoelliptic iff,
$$
\vert\zeta\vert\rightarrow \infty\ \text{on char $P$}\Longrightarrow
\vert\text{Im }\zeta\vert\rightarrow \infty.
$$
This result can be considered as one of the most important in the theory of constant coefficients partial differential operators. Note that if you are interested in analytic regularity, that is to the property $(\flat$) for the analytic singular support (the complement of the largest open subset where the distribution is analytic), you get that $(\flat$) is equivalent to ellipticity, that is to
$$
\forall \xi\in \mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}, \ P_m(\xi)\not=0,
\tag{$\natural$}$$
where $P_m$ is the principal symbol of $P(D)$:
if $m$ is the degree of $P$,
$$
P(\xi)=\sum_{\substack{\alpha \in \mathbb N^n\\\vert \alpha\vert\le m}}
a_\alpha \xi^\alpha, \qquad
P_m(\xi)=\sum_{\substack{\alpha \in \mathbb N^n\\\vert \alpha\vert=m}}
a_\alpha \xi^\alpha.
$$
A direct application of these criteria shows that the heat equation
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\Delta_x$ is hypoelliptic $C^\infty$ without being analytic-hypoelliptic. The volume II of Hörmander's treatise *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators* contains an extensive study of PDE with constant coefficients.

Comment: $\text{Char }P$ is not a manifold in general unless you make some further assumption on $P$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have said characteristic set. I have modified that.

Answer (score 5):

This is in a slightly different direction, but I'll add a recent observation from [*Reconstruction of generic anisotropic stiffness tensors from partial data around one polarization*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.03312) by de Hoop, Lassas, Várilly-Alvarado and myself concerning the elastic wave equation parametrized by the stiffness tensor field.
Because this is a vector valued system of hyperbolic PDEs, there are several polarizations and the waves of different polarizations typically have different speeds.
By studying the algebraic geometry of the characteristic variety we showed that generically a measurement of a little bit of the variety for a single polarization determines the material parameter (the stiffness tensor) uniquely.

Some polarizations are easier to measure than others and one often has partial directional data.
It therefore makes sense to ask to what extent the material parameter is determined by such partial information about the kinematics (travel speeds of singularities) of the solutions.
The results are only generic (and do indeed not hold for all stiffness tensors for several reasons), so in some sense anisotropy of the material makes the conclusions stronger than they are for isotropic materials.
This makes it easier to solve some inverse problems for elastic waves than previously thought.

Comment: This sounds very cool and impressive.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment but it was too long.

This is a very beautiful question and supports a few different interesting generalizations.

1. Instead of a single differential operator, you can consider a system of linear PDEs and naturally they can be associated with an intersection of algebraic varieties.
2. You have more generally the abstract correspondence between linear operators and functions holomorphic at 0. In a single variable differential operator setting this is already rich with identities such as the famous $e^{a\frac{d}{dx}} = f(x+a)$ and the less famous $f(2x) = e^{\ln(2) x \frac{d}{dx}}$. You can look at the generalization in this direction by considering some truly arbitrary linear operator and naturally mapping it to its function dual via taylor series. We consider an example below:

$$ \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n,m} \frac{\partial ^{n+m}}{\partial ^n x \partial^my}  \rightarrow  \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n,m} x^n y^m $$

And so now instead of mapping systems of finite order differential operators to intersections of algebraic varieties. You can look directly mapping arbitrary linear operator equations to intersections of multivariable analytic functions. The latter being strange yet interesting because it connects analytic properties of your linear operator system to analytic properties of the underlying intersection of analytic functions.